# Why does Spark History Server not show completed applications in local-cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm testing a spark program in local-cluster mode: I've set my spark.home property to $SPARK_HOME (pointing to spark installation directory). And I've launched spark history server with spark.history.fs.logDirectory pointing to file:/tmp/spark-events. however, when I successfully execute a test and quit. The history server doesn't show anything, the /tmp/spark-events folder is empty. How to make spark history server recognize my spark program running in local-cluster mode?

Answer (score 3):

Enable collecting events in your Spark tests using `spark.eventLog.enabled` Spark property and start over.